# ServiceStack 5.0.0 - Error CS0012

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, servicestack

Since I upgraded my Xamarin.Forms project to ServiceStack 5, I receive this message:

> CS0012 The type "IReturn<>" is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'ServiceStack.Interfaces, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=02c12cbda47e6587'.

References are already added. I have no idea how to fix this. Is anyone experiencing the same issue?

Edit: I use Xamarin Forms as a Shared Project, if that matters.

I already reinstalled v4.5.14, but the error still comes up.

Comment: You should not have any v4.5.14 references, only v5. Can you put a stand-alone repro on GitHub so I can investigate?

Comment: I don't have any, only when reinstalling the old version

Comment: If you’re trying to mix between .NET Standard and .NET Framework projects, you can try installing ServiceStack.Client.Core to force referencing the .NET Standard builds. If it’s still an issue we’d need a repro.